# Custom Invoice PDF

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

I'm trying to customize the PDF exported by Magento 2 but getting some issues:

> etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf" 
            type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf" />
```

Even after recompiling with `bin/magento setup:di:compile`, nothing seems to change when I download an invoice PDF (tested with `exit("test");` in the constructor of the class).

So I tried also overriding `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice` and this time, an error is thrown in the apache error.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Pdf\\Items\\AbstractItems::setPdf() must be an instance of Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Pdf\\AbstractPdf, instance of Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Order\\Pdf\\Invoice given, called in /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php on line 841 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/AbstractItems.php:139\nStack trace:

#0 /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php(841): Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Pdf\\Items\\AbstractItems->setPdf(Object(Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Order\\Pdf\\Invoice))

#1 /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php(159): Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Order\\Pdf\\AbstractPdf->_drawItem(Object(Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Invoice\\Item), Object(Zend_Pdf_Page), Object(Magento\\Sales\\Model\\Order\\Interceptor))

#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Invoice/AbstractInvoice/PrintAction.php(57): Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Order\\Pdf\\Invoice->getPdf(Array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first error message, I assume that your custom model does not extend from `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf`. This should be the case.

Comment: Correct. I was extending from  custom AbstractPdf to directly customize any PDF

Answer (score 0):

Please change your construction as i given.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig, \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory, \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate, \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation, \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer, array $data = array()) {
        parent::__construct($paymentData, $string, $scopeConfig, $filesystem, $pdfConfig, $pdfTotalFactory, $pdfItemsFactory, $localeDate, $inlineTranslation, $addressRenderer, $data);
    }
```

check after that.

Comment: `Errors during compilation:
 Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf
  Incompatible argument type: Required type: array. Actual type: \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data; File: 
/var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php`
^_^